# Powershell Command builder

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, powershell

I am trying make a c# application which runs sharepoint cmdlets in management shell 2010.

I have tried below code:

```
protected void ExecuteCode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            RunspaceConfiguration config = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();

            PSSnapInException OExSnapIn = null;

            PSSnapInInfo pssnap = config.AddPSSnapIn("Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell", out OExSnapIn);

            Runspace cmdlet = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(config);

            cmdlet.Open();

            RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(cmdlet);

            scriptInvoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted");

             Pipeline pipeline = cmdlet.CreatePipeline();

            Command cmd = new Command("Get-SPFarm");

            pipeline.Commands.Add(cmd);

            pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");

            Command cmdnew = new Command("Get-SPWebApplication");

            cmdnew.Parameters.Add("Identity","http://clbblr-6166/sitesnew");

            pipeline.Commands.Add(cmdnew);

            IEnumerable<PSObject> output = pipeline.Invoke();

            pipeline.Stop();

            cmdlet.Close();

            StringBuilder results = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (PSObject obj in output)

            {

                results.AppendLine(obj.ToString());

            }

        }
```

but it throws an exception like this

[image]

note: I found out that sharepoint management 2010 will load powershell 3.0 and as my code targets 2.0 it is throwing weird errors.

even in the sharepoint management shell window I get this below error:

[image]

I have installed all the updates also..
I found that I need to uninstall an update like this " Windows6.1-KB2506143-x64" 
I did it still am clueless of what am missing.

hope am clear to u.
Any help is much appreciated.

in simple terms I want to see the output in the output below :
[image]

Comment: to add to this: am using 64bit machine.. trying to use sharepoint 2010

Answer (score 0):

In c# use .net framework 3.5 - then it might work.
For PowerShell console: Edit the powershell shortcut and add "-version 2" behind the powershell.exe (in your startmenu or toolbar).

Comment: hi @max: thanks a ton for response.. I have already set the target for the powershell console as "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe -Version 2.0 -NoExit " & ' C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\CONFIG\POWERSHELL\Registration\\sharepoint.ps1 ' "  but it didn't help

Comment: and regarding the framework: if I change it to 3.5 it says.. Error..The type or namespace name 'Automation' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Management' (are you missing an assembly reference?)